# Can we get community base url without apex?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

I want to get community base url in my lightning component without apex. Right now I am using the design component to store the value but that is not optimal as I have multiple page references and typing each of them in the community builder is really hard and error prone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can retrieve the current page url in your JavaScript controller. And set the value of attribute in your component for later use according to your requirement.

Component

```
 <aura:attribute name="cbaseURL" type="String"/>
```

JS Controller

```
 var urlString = window.location.href;
 var baseURL = urlString.substring(0, urlString.indexOf("/s"));
 component.set("v.cbaseURL", baseURL);
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

As RedDevil highlighted that using window.location can create issues with Microsoft browsers. I tend to search a bit and find out interesting result. So I'd like to all the readers must go through this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652816/what-is-the-difference-between-document-location-href-and-document-location) to read about the details and use whatever suits you best.

However the widely accepted answer says:

> document.location is a synonym for window.location that has been
>   deprecated for almost as long as JavaScript has existed. Don't use it.
>
> location is a structured object, with properties corresponding to the
>   parts of the URL. location.href is the whole URL in a single string.
>   Assigning a string to either is defined to cause the same kind of
>   navigation, so take your pick.
>
> I consider writing to location.href = something to be marginally
>   better as it's slightly more explicit about what it's doing. You
>   generally want to avoid just location = something as it looks
>   misleadingly like a variable assignment. window.location = something
>   is fine though.